# How to display column value from database using PHP (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to get the value of a column `parent_affiliate_id` in table1  WHERE the `affiliate_id = $get_id` to store it in  `$parent_traced_id` and display it.

I'm new in WordPress. Please help me. Thank you in advance

```
                    global $wpdb;
                    $table1 = $wpdb->prefix . "uap_mlm_relations";
                    $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT *
                                            FROM $table1
                                            WHERE affiliate_id=%d", $get_id);
                    foreach($results as $row){ 
                        $parent_traced_id = $row->parent_affiliate_id;
                    }

                    echo"$parent_traced_id ";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you are storing value in on variable called  'parent_traced_id' it will store only last value which will be looped. You can use array instead of using variable, so it will store all values which will be looped in for-loop. and you are displaying variable using echo "$parent_traced_id"; use echo $parent_traced_id. And to display all values use print_r($parent_traced_id).

```
               global $wpdb;
                $table1 = $wpdb->prefix . "users";

                $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT *
                                        FROM ".$table1);

                foreach($results as $row){ 
                    $row_id[] = $row->ID;
                }
                 print_r($row_id);
```

Comment: Uhm how do you display only the first value?  And is the query in your comment correct I think it lacks one closing quotation.  Thabk you very much for you answer!

Comment: If you want to display only first value stored in array then you can use echo $row_id[0];